# Make elements in list different colors HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am making a navigation bar that uses the unordered list:

```css
#nav {
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
}

#nav li {
 display:inline;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-family: arial black;
}

#nav li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:423727;
 background-color: F79D28;
 padding:8px 19px;
 border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

#nav li a:hover{ 
 background-color: FFA42E;
}

#cart {
 margin-right: 240px;
 margin-top: 1px;
 float: right;
 background-color: 57BF22;
}
```

```html
<ul id ="nav">
<li><a href ="product_list.php">PRODUKTER</a></li>
<li><a href ="installation_guide.php">INSTALLATIONSGUIDE</a></li>
<li><a href ="ssd_info.php">OM SSD</a></li>
<li id = "cart"><a href ="cart.php">0 produkt(er) 0.00 kr</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have given the last element an `id = "cart"`, this is because it is this element that i want to make a different background color. The desired background color on the cart is `background-color: 57BF22` which i also put in the `#cart`. The `background-color` does not change though, it is still using the background color from `#nav list a`, how would i change it to `background-color: 57BF22;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing the `#` that indicates the hex-code for colors, plus if you want to change the `li#cart` **link**, then you need to be more specific and use something like this

- `#nav li#cart a`  or
- `#nav #cart a`

---

#### To Read:

- [Colors in hexadecimal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Color)
- [CSS Specificity](http://blog4coders.com/css-specificity)

---

#### here is a snippet

```css
#nav {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial black;
}
#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#423727;
  background-color:#F79D28;
  padding: 8px 19px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color:#FFA42E;
}
#nav li#cart a {
  margin-right: 240px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  float: right;
  background-color:#57BF22;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="product_list.php">PRODUKTER</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="installation_guide.php">INSTALLATIONSGUIDE</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="ssd_info.php">OM SSD</a>
  </li>
  <li id="cart"><a href="cart.php">0 produkt(er) 0.00 kr</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: not only the color code is miswritten, but the selector specifity is ... not specific enough either : https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/  +1

Comment: I was wondering if I should link that in my answer but I decided to choose one more "friendly" to read and therefore easy to learn IMHO :)

Comment: thank you, hex colors works without the #-sign but i did not specify it correctly. Thanks for enlighting me!

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in  your code.

Instead of this:

```
background-color: 57BF22;
```

Use this:

```
background-color: #57BF22;
```

In fact, the hexadecimal values throughout your code are incorrect. You need to preface each value with a `#`. Learn more on [MDN `background-color` syntax section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color#Syntax).

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```css
#nav {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: arial black;
}
#nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: 423727;
  background-color:#F79D28;
  padding: 8px 19px;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
#nav li a:hover {
  background-color:#FFA42E;
}
#nav li#cart a {
  margin-right: 240px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  float: right;
  background-color:#57BF22;
}
```

What you are doing wrong is not putting the character "#" to the color code. As this is called a hexadecimal it requires this character otherwise CSS will not detect that as anything

Comment: so you literally are using others answer? thats not nice at all ;)

Comment: not really, where have i answered the same as you? I jsut saw the question and then posted what i think was right ..I am here to help not to argue who copied who, so best to not act childish about it.